# Why I get nan as result of most of my results

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I have Reduse Function in mongoDB. I want to print AVG of cities in each State.
I get only one correct result and The rest will be nan

map function

```
function map(){
key = {state : this.state};
values = { numberOfCities:1, statePop: this.pop}; 
emit(key, values)}
```

and the reduce function

```
function reduce(key , values){
 numberOfCities = 0.0;
 statePop = 0.0;
 avg = 0.0;
for (i in values){
    numberOfCities += values[i].numberOfCities;
    statePop += values[i].statePop;
    avg = statePop/numberOfCities;
}
return  avg}
```

[image]

IF I return statePop with numberOfCities, I will get correct number, but if I return operation statePop/numberOfCities I will get nan value for it

The error

[image]

json file ( this is one line of json file )

```
{ "_id" : "20002", "city" : "WASHINGTON", "loc" : [ -76.990055, 38.902365 ], "pop" : 56756, "state" : "DC" }
```

Comment: can you console.log( statePop, numberOfCities) ?

Comment: How are you calling `reduce()`, and why aren't you using the `key` argument?

Comment: Ammresh Venugopal, I do not understand your point

Comment: Shouldn't you calculate the average outside the loop?

Comment: nnnnnn, I run map and reduce in python                                                map = Code(open('e-map.js' , 'r').read())
reduce = Code (open('e-reduce.js', 'r').read())
results = db.zipcodes.map_reduce(map , reduce , 'result')
for result in results.find().limit(9):
 print result

Comment: Burhan Khaled, I will get same result . only one state correct and the rest are nan

Comment: @AliAl-ali Since you are dividing by a value which was previously 0 (`numberOfCities`). I want you to add this statement: `console.log( statePop, numberOfCities) ` before `avg = statePop/numberOfCities;`<-this line

Comment: Amresh Venugopal , I get errors

Comment: What are the errors? @AliAl-ali

Comment: @AliAl-ali Your variables are still 0 as per the image. It therefore is doing a `0/0` which is `NaN`

Comment: Even if I change all of them to 1, I will get same problem nan

Answer (score 0):

`i` is an instance of your value object, not an index. So instead of`values[I].property` use `i.property`

Comment: I will get nan for all  avg

Comment: Is this.pop a valid number?

Comment: yes. I edit the question to add a sample of json file